# python3: Read huge file (~ 800 Gb), split the lines by condition, and append them to the end of new files in a memory-efficient way

Tags: python, memory-management, append

I’m learning python 3, and I’m dealing with a huge txt file (~800Gb).
The enclosed function 'kmers_dic' while it read the main file, if the condition in if statement is satisfied, it should append the line in the previously created files (these files are 1024 and they are named with content of the kmers variable). The function work fine with a subset of the principal file, but when I run the code using the main file, my job is killed because I reached a memory usage limit.

```
def OpenFiles(i):
    '''
    A switch to handle file opening and reduce duplicated code
    '''
    open_method = {
        "gz": gzip.open,
        "norm": open
    }
    return open_method[i]

def rows(f, chunksize=102400, sep='\n'):
        """
        Read a file where the row separator is '\n' lazily.
        Default chunk size: 102400kB 100Mb.
        Usage:
        >>> with open('big.csv') as f:
        >>>     for r in rows(f):
        >>>         process(r)
        """
        curr_row = ''
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunksize)
            if chunk == '': # End of file
                break
            while True:
                i = chunk.find(sep)
                if i == -1:
                    break
                yield curr_row + chunk[:i]
                curr_row = ''
                chunk = chunk[i+1:]
            curr_row += chunk
    
            
    def kmers_dic(input_file,kmers,out_dir):
        '''
            file writing by kmers
        '''
        #kmers_dic = set()
        count_line=0
        count_line_1=0
        if input_file.endswith('.gz'):
            nano_read = OpenFiles('gz')
        else:
            nano_read = OpenFiles('norm')
        
        with nano_read(input_file, 'rt') as nano_f:
            chunk = rows(nano_f,chunksize=2024,sep='\n')
            for line in chunk:
                
                count_line+=1
                count_line_1+=1
                
                sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % count_line)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                
                line = line.strip('\n')
                line = line.split()
                if line[2] in kmers:
                    kmer = line[2]
                    Out_f_name = out_dir+line[2]+'.lib'
                    file1 = open(Out_f_name, 'a')
                    ##file1.write('\t'.join(line) + '\n') # print entire line
                    file1.write('\t'.join(line[1:4:]+line[6:9:]+line[9:13:]+line[15:]) + '\n')
                    file1.close()
        print("lines: ",count_line_1)
```

I'm not understanding where is the issue.
Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance!
Best.

Comment: I don't think this would make *too* much of a difference, but you could avoid making copies in `chunk = chunk[i+1:]` by doing `i=0` outside the loop and then `j = chunk.find(sep, i)` or something inside. Are there any super-long lines in the file that could be affecting things?

Comment: How long is a normal line, maybe your file is corrupted and missing a bunch of line separators. Maybe put a conditional in to check for really long lines - `for line in chunk: if len(line) == chunksize: print(count_line); break`. Or run it in your debugger and put a conditional breakpoint there.

Comment: Are you running out of screen memory trying to print 800 million `count_line`s? try logging them to a file instead [https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

Comment: I tested `rows` with lines length of 8k and chunksize of 1k and it works fine.

Comment: The rows length is not the same for all the rows and I don’t know how much variable it is. I’ll try the different solutions you guys suggest and i let you know !!

Answer (score 1):

`curr_row += chunk` causes you keep all chunks in memory until you run out of free memory.

Comment: That's only true if `chunk.find(sep)` keeps returning `-1`, i.e., if there is one extremely long line.

Comment: To me it looks like any time a line separator is found the line is yielded then curr_row is assigned an empty string so it shouldn't accumulate more than one line - do you see something different?

Comment: yes, it expects at least one very long line. But because the code creates multiple different copies/modifications of given line string it's possible to reach this race condition. It all depends on the data in give ~800Gb file. Also, if last character in file isn't `\n` then last line never yields out of `rows` function

Comment: The issue is related to line length. There is an extremely long line or line without `\n`. How can I solve it? I’m producing again the input file, because it sounds strange. But it’s also true as the line length in this file can differ, but I don’t expect something so weird.